# Inkscape place object on a hook (through the back out the front)

Tags: inkscape

I have two objects, one is a `hook` and the other is a circle with a hole in it. How can I give the illusion of the hook going behind the object through the hole and out of the front?

Currently the hook is in front of the object.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply cut out the part of the hook that should be behind the PHP symbol and send it to the back.

To cut out a part of a larger object, draw the shape of the cut (a simple rectangle or circle will do), place it where you'd like to cut the object, select both and apply the Division boolean operation (Ctrl /).

Comment: I am not too familiar with `Union`, `Division`, etc. (Or inkscape for that matter), but doing what you said and using `Difference` seemed to work. I couldn't get `Division` to work, so maybe I was doing something wrong, or just didn't understand what it was doing... But I got the result I was looking for!